# Заголовок не хочет выравниваться по вертикали

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не могу выровнять заголовок, флексбокс не помогает.
 Высоту родительскому контейнеру задал. 
Пытался делать элемент строчным, тоже не сработало. 
В интернете ответа так и не нашел, ничто не помогает. 
код

```css
.html .page {
    background: #2a2c2f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    
    .header {
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    .header {
    background-image: url(../images/header-bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-height: 1080px;
    }
    
    .nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    
    .nav__link {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: white;
    }
    
    .nav__item {
    margin-left: 135px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    }
    
    .nav__item:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 35px;
    }
    
    .nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .header__navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }
    
    .header__title {
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 90px;
    max-width: 998px;
    height: 120px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    .html .page{
    background: #2a2c2f;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
    .wrapper{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }
    .header{
    width:100%;
    }
    .header{
    background-image: url(../images/header-bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:1920px;
    min-height:1080px;
    
    }
    
    
    .nav__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    height:auto;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    
    
    }
    .nav__link{
    display:flex;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color:white;
    }
    .nav__item{
    margin-left:135px;
    margin-right:35px;
    }
    .nav__item:first-of-type{
    margin-left:35px;
    
    }
    .nav__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    .header__navigation{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    }
    .header__title{
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 90px;
    max-width:998px;
    height:120px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    color:white;
    
    }
    .wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    }
    
    
    }
    
    .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body class="page">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">


        <nav class="nav__wrapper">
            <ul class="header__navigation">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">TEAM</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">BOOKING</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav__item-img"><img src="./images/Vector.png"></div>
            <ul class="header__navigation">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">MENU</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">GALERIE</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">EVENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1 class="header__title">hungry people</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как пример Вы можете использовать `margin auto` для центрирования.

```css
.html .page {
    background: #2a2c2f;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-image: url(https://scx2.b-cdn.net/gfx/news/hires/2019/4-space.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-height: 1080px;
}

.nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.nav__link {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: white;
}

.nav__item {
    margin-left: 135px;
    margin-right: 35px;
}

.nav__item:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 35px;
}

.nav__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header__navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__title {
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 90px;
    max-width: 998px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ff0e0e;
.html .page{
    background: #2a2c2f;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.header{
    width:100%;
}
.header{
    background-image: url(../images/header-bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    max-width:1920px;
    min-height:1080px;

}


.nav__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    height:auto;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;


}
.nav__link{
    display:flex;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color:white;
}
.nav__item{
    margin-left:135px;
    margin-right:35px;
}
.nav__item:first-of-type{
    margin-left:35px;

}
.nav__wrapper{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header__navigation{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.header__title{
    font-size: 96px;
    line-height: 90px;
    max-width:998px;
    height:120px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    color:white;

}
.wrapper{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}


}

.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">


        <nav class="nav__wrapper">
            <ul class="header__navigation">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">TEAM</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">BOOKING</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="nav__item-img"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></div>
            <ul class="header__navigation">
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">MENU</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">GALERIE</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">EVENTS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1 class="header__title">hungry people</h1>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я пытался задавать margin:auto auto; то не работает.

Comment: @Михаил скопируйте код. Всё работает.

Comment: Я по центру изображения пытаюсь расположить. Я код скопировал, оно конечно в центре, но слишком высоко. Я такого результата добивался.

Comment: @Михаил по центру какого изображения? В вопросе ни слова про это не было. Формулируйте свой вопрос правильно! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: текст должен распологатся в самом центре всей страницы. Изображение является бэкграундом, растянутым на все окно( в будущем, пока просто 1920x1080px) Так как высота изображения заданна,я не понимаю почему ничего не помогает расположить текст в центре.

Comment: @Михаил теперь понял. Исправил. Посмотрите, этого добиваетесь?

Comment: У меня почему-то текст перескакивает в самый низ, увеличивая еще и высоту изображения  добавляя скролл. Если убрать марджин, то возвращается в исходное положение.

Comment: @Михаил, этого не может быть, так как margin - действует относительно элемента. 50% - означает середину элемента. Посмотрите пример тут - выложил на codepen https://codepen.io/den131313/pen/VwLvBgg Скопируйте полностью код и добавьте себе. Или выложите на codepen свою страницу с картинками, чтобы видеть, что именно в Вашем случае отображается не корректно.

Comment: @Михаил, подскажите, всё получилось у Вас? Или не получается выложить на codepen?

Comment: Я просто не хотел делать отступы, проще было бы флексом спозиционировать, но забил и сделал прост ос помощью отступов, раз уж флекс не хочет работать.